# How to enable user sharing per instructions?

Tags: nautilus, samba

I have this entry in **.xsession-errors** log

"Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned

```
error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares.         
Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
```

This is in relation to my applets having to be reloaded after every boot. Just wondering how I would enable user sharing, and how it affects my applets ??

Answer (score 16):

Actually, you have to install samba if you want to not see the error. But the use of Samba is for file or printer sharing with other unix or window systems. So you can ignore the error or just install samba.

Comment: This fixes the error for me

Comment: @Mika, Samba is for file sharing as well.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this effects your applets at all, that's probably a different bug. You could just make the directory with sudo:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/samba/usershares
```

But I don't really know what it will do.

Answer (score 4):

I sort this problem creating a group call admin:

```
sudo groupadd admin
```

Check that the admin group is part of the sudoers:

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

Now you add your user to the admin group :

```
sudo usermod -aG admin username
```

you can check if your user is part of the group :

```
sudo cat /etc/group | grep '^admin'
```

this worked for me

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the problem? It seems a bit strange to give yourself extra permissions to work round a nautilus bug.

Comment: this worked for me