# long wait time on Login

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, compiz, login

I have to wait a long time (about 15s) after entering login credentials. I read some other posts but didn't find anything relevant to my situation. In the .xsession-errors log, there are two errors and I think one of them could be the cause of the delayed login.

```
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/user/.compiz/session/10e5e71fff61fc4529136368274098992100000031290040"
```

and the below nautilus error even though I have disabled Personal File Sharing in startup applications.

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255:  
net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
```

If one of these is the reason, please help me resolve it. Or let me know what else I could try out.

**Update**: I removed nautilus-share and dont get that 2nd error anymore.
Any idea what that compiz error means?

Answer (score 0):

To solve nautilus error try with:
I sort this problem creating a group call admin:

sudo groupadd admin

Check that the admin group is part of the sudoers:

sudo cat /etc/sudoers

Now you add your user to the admin group :

sudo usermod -aG admin username

you can check if your user is part of the group :

sudo cat /etc/group | grep '^admin'

Source: [How to enable user sharing per instructions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20854/how-to-enable-user-sharing-per-instructions)

sMl

Comment: Actually I dont need this file share option. Is there a way to completely disable this?

Comment: sudo aptitude remove --purge system-config-samba samba-common-bin samba-common samba